# Calculation the location of Ghost Ball

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Regarding to scheme as follows, when i move Guiding Line (Purple Colored), Ball A (Ghost) will slide around Ball B on red Axis. For this reason, i need to find β angle to calculate the exact location of the Ball A (Ghost) moving around Ball B.

Ball A can never proceed behind of Ball B that's why max. positions should be tangent to Ball B. My constants are α (Guiding Line angle), da (distance of Ball A center to edge of Ball B) and r (Ball radius). (xa, ya) & (xb, yb) center coordinates of Ball A and Ball B are known. β should be described in terms of following constants.

[Explanatory scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CppXm.jpg)

Comment: How does the Guiding Line guide Ball A (Ghost)?

Comment: Now its not Guiding. When i move guiding line, it generates the alpha angle value. Moreover, i know da and r values, that’s why i want to calculate Beta angle to calculate the exact location of Ghost Ball.

Comment: In addition, Ball A and Ball B center coordinates are known so, the issue is to find out Beta angle.

Comment: You may want to proof read your question. "Ball A can never proceed behind of Ball A" makes no sense. Also you might redo the picture with the words in darker colors. Yellow on a white background is almost unreadable. "that's why max. positions should be tangent to Ball B" What should be tangent to Ball B?

Comment: For the record, $\alpha$ is not a constant. It changes with the position of the ghost ball. That makes it a variable. But it is a known variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have an isosceles triangle (the angle "on top" is also $\beta$, where there's the description "Equals $\beta$ in max.Position").

That is, the length of the Guiding Line is also $da + r$.

Thus by the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

$$ \frac{ 2r }{ \sin \alpha} = \frac{ da + r }{ \sin\beta } \implies \sin\beta = \frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \quad \text{, or}~~ \beta = \arcsin\bigl(\frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \bigr)$$
Seemingly this comes from a practical task so presumably all the numbers have values such that the arcsine (inverse of sine) can be taken without a hitch.

Comment: But that works only if the ghost ball is in his arbitrarily chosen maximum position. I interpreted the question as wanting a formula for $\beta$ for any position of the ghost ball.

Comment: @SteveB According to his description, the angle $\alpha$ is defined exactly to let the ghost ball be at the max position. Of course, maybe your reading is correct and I'm wrong (I personally find his framing of the question kind of confusing).

Comment: Call the angle that is not $\alpha$ or $\beta$, i.e., the one that equals $\beta$ in the max position, $\gamma$

Copying and pasting from Lee David Chung Lin's answer. (As Michael O'Donohue once said, plagiarism is the sincerest form of theft.)  

$\frac{ 2r }{ \sin \alpha} = \frac{ da + r }{ \sin\gamma } \implies \sin\gamma = \frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \quad \text{, or}~~ \gamma = \arcsin\bigl(\frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \bigr)$

Then $\beta$ = 180 - $\alpha$ - $\arcsin\bigl(\frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \bigr)$

Comment: @Steve thanks for your reply, for the max. position, i have tried the formula with following values, α=23.0739, da=200, r=50; it is resulted as β=78.463 which is correct, unfortunately when i have tried for the α=18.3573 value, β is resulted as 109.7037 but it must be 33.5816. Finally this angle is narrower than α=23.0739, β value must be less than 78.463.

Comment: Yeah, I failed to account for the fact that $\gamma$ will be obtuse once the ghost ball moves forward enough, specifically for $\alpha$ < 21.8. When $\alpha$ is smaller than that then $\gamma$ = 180 - $\arcsin\bigl(\frac{da + r}{ 2r } \sin\alpha \bigr)$,

Comment: @SteveB, thanks for your clarification, now everything is ok. I just want to ask you that how you have calculated the threshold value for α as 21.8?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. My motherboard died. The cutoff angle should be arcsin(2r/(da+r)), i.e., it should be the value of alpha when gamma is 90 degrees.